# Playing multiple files with MediaPlayerLauncher on windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

MediaPlayer launcher launches playback with "next track" and "previous track" controls, but it does not respond. How can I make use of these controls in playing multiple tracks?

Answer (score 0):

The [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class itself does not give you access to the **Next** and **Previous** controls.

If you are talking about the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) class, that's a different story. The behavior for that class is circular, so as long as there is media to play, it will iterate through tracks when **Next** or **Previous** is called. What is the non-responsive behavior that you are talking about? Are there tracks that can be played in the queue?

Comment: I was talking about MediaPlayerLauncher class and not MediaPlayer. When the mediaplayer is launched I could see next and previos track controls, but of no use in pressing that. Is there anyway I can make use of those control to play a list of media files?